# How to get type of one specific prop of a react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Imagine you import a `React.Component` (let's call it `Foo`) from any library (e.g. from `node_modules`). Now you want to extract the type of a prop (let's call it `complexProp`) from `Foo`, so you can use it elsewhere.

**Example**

Foo.tsx:

```
interface FooProps <P /*some generic stuff here*/> {
    complexProp: /*some super weird type you can not simply copy*/;
}

export class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps> {
    //...
    public render(){
        //...
        lookAtComplexProp(this.props.complexProp)
        //...
    }
}

function lookAtComplexProp(complexProp: /* I need the type of Foo.props.complexProp here*/) {
    //...
}
```

- Is this somehow possible?
- Exspecially, is this possible without
  knowing anything about the code behind `Foo`? In other words, is a
  syntax like `type complexPropType = Foo.complexProp.getType();`
  possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type query to get the type of any property of the interface. A simple type query has the form `Type['PropName']`. Instead of `'PropName'` you can also use any string literal type or a union of them all representing keys of the target type. In your case it could look something like this:

```
function lookAtComplexProp<P /*copy constraint here*/>(complexProp: FooProps<P>['complexProp']){
    //...
}
```

Or if you already know for what `P` you want the `complexProp`:

```
function lookAtComplexProp(complexProp: FooProps<number /* or other type */ >['complexProp']){
    //...
}
```

Or if your interface has a default generic parameter you can omit the type parameter:

```
interface FooProps <P = number> {
    complexProp: { complexStuff: P};
}

function lookAtComplexProp(complexProp: FooProps['complexProp']){
    //...
}
```

You can also define a type alias for it just as you would for any type. But again depending on what you want to do there are options:

```
type myComplexType<P /*copy constraint here*/> = FooProps<P>['complexProp'] // you want the type alias to be generic so can get the type for any P.
type myComplexType = FooProps<number>['complexProp'] // you want complexProp type for a specific type argument
type myComplexType = FooProps['complexProp'] // FooProps has a default type argument
```

Comment: Is there a way to save the type, so you don't have to write it like this always?
`type myComplexType = /* set type once */;` and then only reference `myComplexType` everywhere you need it.

Comment: @Truntle sure, you can define a type alias for any type, edited the anser with the new info